# Redirecting domain to subdomain with htaccess

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm having trouble redirecting my domain to a subdomain.

My domain is **www.example.com** and I want all traffic to go to **aa.example.com**

I tried the following code in htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www?\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^index\.php?$ http://new.example.com [R=301,L]
```

But then this happens:

**example.com/aa.example.com**

which obviously returns a 'page not found'. I've had a look at similar questions but I'm inexperienced with these things and can't solve the problem.

Comment: In case anyone else has this problem: I realised that I was putting my original code in the wrong place. There were two instances of 'RewriteEngine on' in the htaccess file for my Wordpress site. I put it in the second one and I should have put it in the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://new.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Make sure to test this in a new browser to avoid old browser caches.

Comment: Oh dear! I've run into a problem because I left some important information out of my question. I've got my domain (www.example.com) and subdomain (aa.example.com) as two sites on a network in Wordpress. After setting the redirect I can't access my network dashboard because an endless loop has been created, and I can't access my domain (www.example.com) dashboard because it redirects to the subdomain dashboard.